# Using NDSLib, how to configure video modes to both print text and draw bitmaps on both screens?

Tags: c++, console, nintendo

In a `NDS` application, i'd like `print text` and `draw bitmaps` on both top and bottom screens.
I have been able to setup code to either draw bitmaps or just print text to console.

If I try to enable both at the same time i only get garbage. My guess is there is a memory conflict between `VRAM banks` used by console background (for storing characters sprites) and background buffer used to draw pixels on screen.

My questions is : **how should i configure video modes to be able to draw text and bitmaps on top and bottom screen ?** If not possible, because there is not enough memory, a solution having only text on top screen is also acceptable.

Here is code :

```
#include <nds.h> 
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    PrintConsole top, bottom;

    //1) bitmap init
    videoSetMode(MODE_5_2D);  
    videoSetModeSub(MODE_5_2D);
    bgInit(3, BgType_Bmp16, BgSize_B16_256x256, 0, 0);
    bgInitSub(3, BgType_Bmp16, BgSize_B16_256x256, 0, 0);

    //2) console init, incompatible with 1)
    consoleInit(&top, 0, BgType_Text4bpp, BgSize_T_256x256, 0, 0, true, true);
    consoleInit(&bottom, 0, BgType_Text4bpp, BgSize_T_256x256, 0, 0, false, true);

    while (1) {            
        swiWaitForVBlank();
        //draw pixels on screens
        for (int y = 0; y < 192; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
                BG_GFX[x + (y << 8)] = ARGB16(1, x + y, 32, y * x);
                BG_GFX_SUB[x + (y << 8)] = ARGB16(1, 32, y, y * x);
            }
        }
        //print text to console 
        consoleSelect(&top);
        printf("top");
        consoleSelect(&bottom);
        printf("bottom");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that asking this don't break Nintendo Non-disclosure_agreement (NDA)?

Comment: @Zhen: This looks like *libnds* code, which is a library used for homebrew. There's no NDA to violate if that's the case.

Comment: I think you misunderstood: you don't need to skip the first 32 rows when you're changing the MapBase of the background. It's only if changing the MapBase *doesn't* work that you might need to do that.

Comment: I tried both of your examples without skipping any rows and both produced garbage. I also try many mapBases values before asking the question on GDSE and everything failed, that why i reset them to zero in the question (i forget to tell that). What worked for me was to used 2 and 1 as mapBase (as you suggested) AND skipping rows.

Comment: @tigrou: The reason it doesn't work is because you're loading the background into the wrong place in VRAM (and I should have noticed that earlier). I've updated my post with the proper code.

Comment: I tried what you said (to use `bgGetGfxPtr()`) and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's take a look at the [signatures](http://libnds.devkitpro.org/a00107.html#ae3621ba14f10ec1c8d4223ede66a9ff7) of the [functions](http://libnds.devkitpro.org/a00156.html#gaf2ba2b415bf8e02ccc0b30c55f878496):

```
PrintConsole* consoleInit  ( PrintConsole *  console,  
  int  layer,  
  BgType  type,  
  BgSize  size,  
  int  mapBase,  
  int  tileBase,  
  bool  mainDisplay,  
  bool  loadGraphics  
 ) 

bgInit  ( int  layer,  
  BgType  type,  
  BgSize  size,  
  int  mapBase,  
  int  tileBase  
 )
```

In both of your calls, you're asking for the two different parts to use the same mapBase and tileBase - in other words, the same area of VRAM.

To make matters worse, you're actually asking the console to overwrite its own memory - it'll use the same VRAM for the map and the tiles.

There's a [very handy tool online](http://mtheall.com/vram.html) for checking these VRAM allocation conflicts, and you can fiddle around with it to find some good numbers for you.

However, there is one big problem: your 256x256 background is going to use up a full bank of VRAM.

The NDS has 2 graphics engine, a "main" engine and a "sub" engine. The main engine has access to [much more VRAM](http://mtheall.com/banks.html#) than the sub engine, which can only use one 128KB bank for backgrounds - and the console also counts as a background.

You will therefore have to exploit the fact that the screen is only 256x192. The simple way would be to just move the console to the end of the bank, but that isn't possible on the sub engine.

Instead, you'll have to move your background deeper into VRAM, say to map base 1 (16K), while the console occupies base 0 for the 4KB of tiles and base 2 (4KB in) for the 2KB map.

Note that you *must* limit your background with this approach.

That means you'll want to do the [following initializations](http://mtheall.com/vram.html#T0=3&NT0=128&MB0=2&TB0=0&S0=0&T3=6&NT3=32&MB3=1&TB3=0&S3=1):

```
PrintConsole top, bottom;
videoSetMode(MODE_3_2D);
videoSetModeSub(MODE_3_2D);

consoleInit(&top, 0, BgType_Text4bpp, BgSize_T_256x256, 2, 0, true, true);
consoleInit(&bottom, 0, BgType_Text4bpp, BgSize_T_256x256, 2, 0, false, true);
bgInit(3, BgType_Bmp16, BgSize_B16_256x256, 1, 0);
bgInitSub(3, BgType_Bmp16, BgSize_B16_256x256, 1, 0);
```

(The tool uses BgSize_B16_256x192 when used like this, but libnds doesn't define that constant, so I've changed it.)

There is some chance that the actual console or some emulators will still break with this, because you're allocating beyond the 128KB limit, but as long as you don't try to *write* beyond, you should be okay. If it turns out that it still fails, another option would be to use this:

```
PrintConsole top, bottom;
videoSetMode(MODE_3_2D);
videoSetModeSub(MODE_3_2D);

mainBg = bgInit(3, BgType_Bmp16, BgSize_B16_256x256, 0, 0);
subBg = bgInitSub(3, BgType_Bmp16, BgSize_B16_256x256, 0, 0);

consoleInit(&top, 0, BgType_Text4bpp, BgSize_T_256x256, 2, 0, true, true);
consoleInit(&bottom, 0, BgType_Text4bpp, BgSize_T_256x256, 2, 0, false, true);
```

but *scroll the background down* by 32 pixels (`bgScroll(mainBg, 0, 32);`)  and make sure you either have 32 unused rows of pixels at the top of your 256x256 image, or load your 256x192 image into the appropriate place in VRAM. The console will still clobber parts of the memory allocated for your background, but it will be a part that won't be shown, so it won't be a problem.

EDIT: There is one thing I forgot to point out; this block:

```
    for (int y = 0; y < 192; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            BG_GFX[x + (y << 8)] = ARGB16(1, x + y, 32, y * x);
            BG_GFX_SUB[x + (y << 8)] = ARGB16(1, 32, y, y * x);
        }
    }
```

*assumes the background uses base 0*, which obviously is no longer the case.

Instead of using BG_GFX directly, store the return values from bgInit and bgInitSub and send them to `bgGetGfxPtr` to get the proper starting address:

```
    u16* mainPtr = bgGetGfxPtr(mainId);
    u16* subPtr = bgGetGfxPtr(subId);
    for (int y = 0; y < 192; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
            mainPtr[x + (y << 8)] = ARGB16(1, x + y, 32, y * x);
            subPtr [x + (y << 8)] = ARGB16(1, 32, y, y * x);
        }
    }
```